# Convolutional Neural Networks - Non square inputs

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have been doing some reading on convolutional neural networks and I realized that the inputs are always squared images. So I was wondering how I can train a CNN to detect people (upright) since the ground truth (bounding box) would be rectangular. Would it be ok to resize the cropped image to a square ?

Thanks.

Comment: Convolutional networks can accept any rectangular image size, not just squares. Have you tried simply training a model with a rectangular input?

It's possible you are referring to a specific CNN with a square input (ie, VGG). Even in this case, you can pass in a differently shaped input, as long as you retrain any fully-connected layers. Check out the documentation for Keras' VGG16 as an example.